# delete all .csv file content in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

so, my program will replace the old data with new data which is the program will put in same .csv file. and after i run the program it is not replaced. below is my code.

```
                        TEXTFILE = open("data.csv", "w")

                        for i in book_list:
                            TEXTFILE.write("{},{},{},{}".format(i[0],i[1],i[2],i[3]))

                        TEXTFILE.close()
```

book_list is the list that save new data to stored
the result i got:

```
k,k,45,c
a,a,65,r
d,s,65,r
as,as,65,r
df,df6,65,r
as,as,6,r
as,as,46,r
as,as,45,r
as,as,56,rk,k,45,r
a,a,65,r
d,s,65,r
as,as,65,r
df,df6,65,r
as,as,6,r
as,as,46,r
as,as,45,r
as,as,56,r
```

it stored to csv with combining old and new content.

well the origininal file is looks like this:

```
k,k,45,r
a,a,65,r
d,s,65,r
as,as,65,r
df,df6,65,r
as,as,6,r
as,as,46,r
as,as,45,r
as,as,56,r
```

idk how to explain. but I expect that the result will change one line with new data in the fourth row. for example, the previous line is k,k,45,r (line 1). and the program will change it become k,k,45,c that way

hope you all can help me :)

Comment: If you could please post what the original file looks like, and your expected output, that would help

Comment: fixed, sorry I have a bit obstacles to edit the post.

Comment: Also post the expected "new content". It would also be helpful to know what the variable `book_list` looks like.

Comment: @KevinJulianto that is very strange. I cannoit reproduce your issue at all. Could it be that the problem is in other part of your code? For example maybe you somehow duplicate contents of `book_list`. Please make sure that `book_list` has what you want it to.

Comment: nope, I just want to write the new data into the same csv file

Comment: @KevinJulianto is there any way you could share all your souces? E.g. code and file you use. Like into a git gist or something.

Comment: guys, thankyou so much for helping me. actually i have a mistake with my program. I append 2 list into book_list and it solved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.truncate()` , if called after opening file it destroys it's content.

```
TEXTFILE = open("data.csv", "w")
TEXTFILE.truncate()

for i in book_list:
    TEXTFILE.write("{},{},{},{}".format(i[0],i[1],i[2],i[3]))   

TEXTFILE.close()
```

I hope I understood you correctly.

Comment: I already change the "w" with "w+" but the result still same. but thankyou btw :)

Comment: @KevinJulianto so did I understood what you are trying to do? You want to overwrite contents?

Comment: @KevinJulianto please try the new version of my code.

Comment: @UpmostScarab, `w` mode should also truncate the file so this shouldnt change anything

Comment: @RNar i suppose you are right. But well i'm tryng to suggest something because I can't even reproduce what's happening there.

Comment: You can write (*i[0:4]) too shorten.